# A free API for rock climbing locations?

Tags: data-request, api, uk, sports

Is there a free API for rock climbing locations in the UK? What I'm thinking of is an API which gets information along the lines of ukclimbing.com, e.g. https://www.ukclimbing.com/logbook/crag.php?id=457.

Failing that, is it possible to scrape the ukclimbing website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaggle hosts the [8a.nu dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/dcohen21/8anu-climbing-logbook), which is scraped from the 8a.nu global climbing logbook.

> This is all of the publicly available information from http://www.8a.nu, the world's largest rock climbing logbook, as of 9/13/2017. <s>Check out https://github.com/dcohen21/8a.nu-Scraper for more information about this project.</s>*

* *Github repo down due to DMCA notice*

[image]

In the table "ascent", you have 4.11 million records. Each has a field "country" where you can filter on UK (ISO 3-letter code is GBR)

---

Registration required to download the data, which is in sqlite format. You can use a library like [datasette](https://github.com/simonw/datasette) to build and API from a sqlite file.

Comment: That github link has the notice "Repository unavailable due to DMCA takedown."

Comment: Might be a good idea to make a local copy of the kaggle dataset. if.you.know.what.i.mean.